# Bootstrap carousel navigation controls too tall

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have a Bootstrap carousel but the left and right navigation control overflow at the bottom of the carousel after the bottom of the image.

[image: Carousel navigation over flow]

Any way to get rid of this overflow of the navigation arrows?

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
<a href="/freshers2015">
<img src="/files/2015/06/journosoc-prefreshers-web.png" alt="First slide"/>
</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
<img src="/files/2015/06/whatjourno.png" alt="Second slide"/>
</div>
</div>
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Edit the post with the code that you are using.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/r2fa3km8/

Comment: Can't work out what the issue is then.